# Casting to my Raspberry Pi running LineageOS

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, lineageos

I'm considering making my own "Android TV" by flashing a build of LineageOS on my raspberry pi and then side-loading apps as-needed.

I'm aware that Netflix and YouTube support the DIAL protocol, since they made it. If I could run a DIAL (“Discovery And Launch”) server on my raspberry pi android device, then I'm sure I could cast to it from my phone or computer.

Amazon Fire TV devices do this with the whisperplay daemon.

Is there an equivalent for Android?

Answer (score 0):

I helped implement Whisperplay.

If you're still interested and want to know what you're in for, open a ticket here and we'll connect: https://github.com/Unofficial-Whisperplay-Fling-Helpline/wp/issues

Edit: You might be able to do this by scavenging parts out of Amazon FlingSDK. Maybe. I have to think about it.